# How to correctly import models in extra modules in Django project?

Tags: python, django

If i want to use some model in extra file in my Django project, i can't do it by this simple way:

```
from myproject_app.models import *
```

because i get this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

To solve this problem, I found this solution:

```
import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
django.setup()
from myproject_app.models import *
```

Ok. It works. But if i want to use any fuction from this extra file in models.py project does not start at all!

Please help me.

Comment: add your setting.py code

Comment: You need to show how you are running this "extra file".

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to register your app in,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    myproject_app,
)
```

Comment: I did not forget, so I can not understand the cause of the problem

Comment: are you running from terminal? or wsgi?

Comment: From terminal in test mode

Comment: @Denis did you activate your virtual env and run `python manage.py shell`?

Answer (score 0):

Add all application you created to INSTALLED_APPS, and as PEP8 perspective never import all models by '*', instead import individually by its name which you are using